# How to build shim from source and enroll keys

Tags: 20.04, grub-efi

## How to build shim from source and enroll keys

I'm trying to build [shim](https://github.com/rhboot/shim) from source and enroll my own keys to the MOK list but it's not working out. Whenever I add the keys everything seems to go well but when I check the enrolled keys list, there is nothing there.

### Steps taken

Dependencies cover the entire post.

```bsh
# Installing dependencies
sudo apt install git build-essential make gnu-efi libelf-dev efitools efibootmgr
```

#### Getting shim

```bsh
# Getting shim
cd ~
mkdir git
cd git
git clone https://github.com/rhboot/shim.git
```

#### Creating keys

```bsh
# Create key
sudo mkdir /testkeys
cd /testkeys
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "/CN=Test Local/" \
    -keyout test.key -out test.crt -days 3650 -nodes -sha256
# Convert to DER format
sudo openssl x509 -in test.crt -out test.cer -outform DER
# Change permissions
sudo chmod 400 test.key
sudo chmod 644 test.cer
```

#### Building shim

```bsh
# Building shim
cd ~/git/shim
make VENDOR_CERT_FILE=/testkeys/test.cer LIBDIR=/usr/lib EFI_PATH=/usr/lib
sudo make EFIDIR=/boot/efi install-as-data
```

#### Installing shim

```bsh
# Copying shim to EFI
sudo cp /usr/share/shim/15/x64/* /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/
```

```bsh
# Registering shim (your drive and partition may be different)
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1 -l \\EFI\\ubuntu\\shimx64.efi -L shim
# List boot entries
#efibootmgr
# Can be deleted with (id is just 0001, 0002, etc..)
#efibootmgr -Bb <id>
```

#### Adding keys to MOK list

```bsh
# Add key to MOK new list
mokutil --import /testkeys/test.cer
# Will be prompted for a password twice
```

```bsh
# Now reboot
sudo reboot
```

On boot, MokManager comes up, asks me to enroll the key, yes, enter the password, everything seems fine, I then press reboot and when booted.

```bsh
# List enrolled keys
mokutil --list-enrolled
#MokListRT is empty
```

How???

### Things I've tried

#### Importing a different key

I tried adding a different key, different from the one used when building shim.

```bsh
# Create key
cd /testkeys
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "/CN=Random Local/" \
    -keyout random.key -out random.crt -days 3650 -nodes -sha256
# Convert to DER format
sudo openssl x509 -in random.crt -out random.cer -outform DER
sudo chmod 400 random.key
sudo chmod 644 random.cer

# Importing it
mokutil --import random.cer

# And reboot
sudo reboot
```

On boot, MokManager comes up, asks me to enroll the key, yes, enter the password, everything seems fine, I then press reboot and when booted.

```bsh
# List enrolled keys
mokutil --list-enrolled
#MokListRT is empty
```

#### Signing shim

I tried signing `shimx64.efi`, `fbx64.efi` and `mmx64.efi` with the key used when building shim.

```bsh
cd /testkeys
# Signing efi binaries
sudo sbsign --key test.key --cert test.crt --output /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
sudo sbsign --key test.key --cert test.crt --output /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/fbx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/fbx64.efi
sudo sbsign --key test.key --cert test.crt --output /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
```

And again importing a key

```bsh
# Import key
mokutil --import random.cer
# And reboot
sudo reboot
```

Same story; on boot, MokManager comes up, asks me to enroll the key, yes, enter the password, everything seems fine, I then press reboot and when booted.

```bsh
# List enrolled keys
mokutil --list-enrolled
#MokListRT is empty
```

### My environment

Freshly installed version of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a Dell XPS 13. I'm aware that Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS comes with shim installed/configured.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might well be that your UEFI is not in Setup Mode, if you start your system with KeyTool.efi, this will show in the header.

I have had a similar problem, and had to delete my PK to get the system into Setup Mode.